# How to enforce argument mutual exclusivity?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to elegantly define a function which required one and only one of its named arguments?

```
def foo (a=None, b=None, c=None):
    if a and b in None and c is None:
        return something for a
    if a in None and b and c is None:
        return something for b
    if a is None and b in None and c:
        return something for c
    raise ValueError("foo requires one and only one of a, b and c",a,b,c)
```

something better than

```
def foo (**args):
    if len(args) != 1:
        raise ValueError("foo: too many or too few args",args)
    arg,val = args.iteritems().next()
    if arg == "a":
        return something for a
    if arg == "b":
        return something for b
    if arg == "c":
        return something for c
    raise ValueError("foo: unknown argument",arg,val)
```

Note also that not only the second version is no shorter than the first one, it also prevents static checkers like pylint from detecting the list of acceptable arguments.

Comment: @JasonHeine That's "at least 1 argument specified", this is "exactly 1 specified".

Comment: This sounds like bad design both for an external user and for developing the code. Why not make three different functions?

Comment: @AlexHall: I am actually wondering about that myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code allows you to easily tell which parameter was not None.

```
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    paramDict = {'a': a, 'b' : b, 'c' : c}
    matches = [x for x in paramDict if paramDict[x] != None]
    if len(matches) != 1:
        raise ValueError("foo requires one and only one of a, b and c")
    else:
        print("parameter %s == %s" % (matches[0], paramDict[matches[0]]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy, you just count the `None`s:

```
if [a,b,c].count(None) != 2:
    raise ValueError("foo requires exactly one argument among a,b and c.")
```